# How to search for a file with partial name in fs nodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, filesystems, node-modules

I'm doing a fetch and download a pdf file from another server with the full file name mentioned, below is my code:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs')
http.createServer((req, resp) => {

   var filename = 'AG1_LN047992593_PB_20200720'
   var url = "\\\\192.168.111.71\\Passbook\\AG1_LN047992593_PB_20200720.pdf";
   
   fs.readFile(url, (err,fileContent) =>
    {
      resp.writeHead(200, 
        {   'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename= ' + filename + '.pdf',
       });
      console.log(err);
      resp.end(fileContent);
    });
  
  }).listen(8081);
  
  console.log('server running on port 8081');
```

here I succeeded in fetching and download that specific file mentioned in *filename* .

However the next stage is to find the file with filename starts from 5th position and ends at 15th position.

example - user enters the filename as **LN047992593** and node should search for all the files in that folder with the files names starting from  5th position and ends at 15th position and fetch and download this file - *AG1_LN047992593_PB_20200720.pdf*.

There will be more than hundred thousands files in that folder with unique file names.

Is there any possible way to achieve this in plain js/node code?

I'm using node version **6.10.0**

Comment: Are you required to stick to node version `6.10.0`? I'm asking because version >= `12.11.1` supports async reading of a directory's contents.

Comment: Yes I have to stick with 6.10.0

Comment: You may use Group 1 of [this](https://regex101.com/r/AO3Xnd/2) regular expression.